# What is the best way to send text file contents to the web browser, file size is around 100 megabytes?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, windows-server-2012, werkzeug

In my project I need to send file content to the web browser. File size vary to few KB to 100 mb. When trying to send large file size contents to browser, browser fails to show full file content.

First I tried with basic approach opening file and read its contents, send data as a response data to browser. But this approach doesn't go well with large files.

Second approach I tried as suggested in [this link](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2011/01/content-length-and-wsgifilewrapper.html) by Graham Dumpleton.

I also tried with X-SendFile approach.

With all approaches I am still struggling with rendering of large file data.

Added Code snippet.

```
def sendFileContent(filePath, block_size=8192):
    fileObject = open(filePath, 'rb')
    data = ''
    try:
        data = fileObject.read(block_size)
        while data:
            yield data
            data = fileObject.read(block_size)
    finally:
        try:
            data.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

def application(environ, start_response):
    filepath = 'C:\logs\ABC.txt'
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(filesize)),])

    file_wrapper = environ.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
        if file_wrapper:
            filelike = open(filepath, 'rb')
            return file_wrapper(filelike, 8192)

        return sendFileContent(filepath)
```

In Apache config I have also made 'EnableSendfile on' changes.

The problem with the above approach is that, when I tried to open 100 MB file browser stops rendering after 60-65 MB. I mean, I can see contents of first 60-65 MB of file, rest is only blank. Browser allow me to scroll up to the end of file, but no content display after 60-65 MB.

I am using Apache 2.4, Python 3.5, MOD_WSGI, Werkzeug technologies on Windows.

Comment: In the context of displaying it, or simply saving the file somewhere? If it's for display, why do you need to display so much data in the first place?

Comment: We need a little more. Show code of things that you tried. Tell what's going wrong? Downloading large files with HTTP should be no problem.

Comment: Added code snippet and problem details.